# Not able to execute testcases in multiple machine through selenium grid

Tags: java, selenium

When we are executing our testcases in multiple machines through selenium grid, where the hub is connected to 3 node machines every time it is executing the testcases in one machine only.
The process through which we are trying to implement this is :

When the execution starts, In **@BeforeMethod** it calls the initialization method where we are first setting the capabilities required to run the testcases in Chrome and then it is starting the grid.

Below is the code written for the selenium grid :

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public static synchronized void initialize(ITestContext context, Method method, @Optional String bsEnvironment)
            throws IOException {

        String customer = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("customer");
        String testName = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getName();
        setTestName(testName);
        String methodName = "";
        m_testMethod = method.getName();
        methodName = testName + "_" + method.getName() + "_" + customer;
        CommonHelper.renameRetryLog(m_logDir, methodName);
        Log.setLog(m_logDir, methodName);

        m_context = context;
        if (m_runOnBrowserStack) {

            if (null == context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("bsEnvironment")
                    || context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("bsEnvironment").isEmpty()) {
                Log.info("Adding bsEnvironment parameter for run on BrowserStack");
                context.getCurrentXmlTest().addParameter("bsEnvironment", bsEnvironment);
            }
        }

        try {

            WebDriver driver = m_driverForThread.get();
}



private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> m_driverForThread = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() {

        @Override
        protected WebDriver initialValue() {
            WebDriver driver = null;
            try {
                driver = loadDesktopDriver();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.info("Initializing Webdriver");
            m_listOfWebDrivers.add(driver);
            return driver;
        }
    };

protected static WebDriver loadDesktopDriver() throws Exception {

        WebDriver driver = null;
        Log.debug("Get Driver for Browser : " + m_browser);

        try {
            if (!m_runOnBrowserStack && null == m_browser) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Browser value should be provided for test");
            }
            driver = getNewDriver(m_browser, "", "", m_context);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.fatal("Error creating a webdriver. Exception message : " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }

        return driver;
    }

public static WebDriver getNewDriver(String browserName, String browserVersion, String platform,
            ITestContext context){

String chromeDriverPath = driverHome + File.separator + FrameworkConstants.chromeDriverExeName;

            if (m_runOnBrowserStack || CommonHelper.isFileExists(chromeDriverPath)) {

                if (!m_runOnBrowserStack)
                    desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

                desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);

                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

                desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",chromeDriverPath);

                if (null != m_gridUrl && !m_gridUrl.isEmpty()) {

                    return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(m_gridUrl), desiredCapabilities);

                } else
                    return new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), desiredCapabilities);

            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(
                        "Chrome Driver path : " + chromeDriverPath + "\n\"" + FrameworkConstants.chromeDriverExeName
                                + "\" not found in driver home path declared in System Environment Variable \""
                                + driverHome + "\"");
            }
```

Comment: how many instances of browser allowed in a single node. if you execute one test, then it will execute on first available node on the grid. if you want check try parallel execution of tests.

Comment: I  am running 5 testcases in asingle testNG  XML  file and trying to  run in the grid. So  it  should distribute in mutilple node but  all the test  cases are running in  single node even if the hub is connected to  3 active node.

Comment: are you running in parallel?

Comment: Yes I am running in parallel.        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite verbose="2" name="Suite Name" parallel="tests"
 thread-count="1">

Comment: how may browser instance configured for a single node?

Comment: update thread count to 5 in xml and try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162497/discussion-between-dev-and-murthi).

Comment: Not allowed to chat sorry